# Super position of small network over big network

Tags: r, gephi

I am working on PPI network and for the network plot I am using Gephi and `rgexf` package. In my network there are 9453 no. of vertices and 36888 connections. So, when  plot the network on gephi we can't analyse anything, so I plot only top 50 nodes network. Now I want to highlight that 50 node's network over the top 100 nodes network. Here the top means the nodes which has highest degree. So is there any way to do it?

This the plot for top 50 nodes, there is one node which is not connected to any of the node in top50:

[image]

I am struggling from few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE - I updated the descriptions**

Ok so this is not totally trivial but not straightforward either. I have created a random network with 500 nodes to show you an example.

1. After you load your network with Gephi you need at least to run the **Average degree** from the statistics.
2. You then go to the **Filters** section, select *Attributes>Range>In-degree*, double-click and press the **Filter** button (**Note:** In your case you should just see **Degree** but the rest still apply)
3. Move the slider to the right so that in the **Context** panel the number of remaining nodes reaches ~*50*

Here is how it looks for me

[image]

**COLORING:**

While you keep the Filter button pressed you can apply a different color to the filtered nodes. In my case I went in *Ranking>Nodes* selected *InDegree* and applied a green color. Note that you can also select *Degree* to get the effect you want. The respective panel looks like that:[image]

This colors only the filtered nodes. Alternatively, you can apply the node brush [image] but then it becomes a bit dull :). There is a 3rd option but I leave it as an exercise :).

The final graph looks like that for me.

[image]

Programmatically you could do something similar in `igraph`. You can select the nodes with top-50 indegrees, assign them a color, assign all the rest a different color and export to GraphML.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, My network is undirected and as you show in your example that in filter> library> attribute> range> in degree. In my case in the range there is no option like that. there is option like SIM, WGH and Weight. And how do you apply the color to that node? Thanks for help.

Comment: @Maulik did you run **Step 1** above? Gephi needs to calculate the degrees on its own before it can display it in a filter or a ranking operation. After you do that you will see a **Degree** filter appearing under *Range filters*. Also exactly beneath the filters' image I give instructions on how to color the nodes. You can also color them one by one by clicking on the *small color bucket icon* on the left of the graph display. Hover the icons to find which one it is, I will try to update the post

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is importing the network to gephi ASIS and compute degree centrality, this will generate a variable with the degree of each vertex in the graph. After that you can use the filter tool (as illustrated in this presentation http://www.clementlevallois.net/gephi/tuto/en/gephi_advanced%20functions_en.pdf) to restrict the number of vertices to work with using the degree variable. That's the easy way.

Alternatively, you can calculate each node's degree using either `igraph` or `sna` packages, and include such as an attribute of your network in the `write.gexf` function.

Comment: Thanks gvegayon, gephi ASIS is different from gephi-0.8.2 beta? How to compute degree centrality in gephi? By using filter tool is it possible to only highlight top nodes over the full network? I don't want to hide the other nodes i just want to give them color transparency.

Comment: Sorry to be so unclear with my reply, what I meant with gephi ASIS (as is) was using the gexf that you already have and do what Yannis P. says.